GCF function testing in python: failed to fetch builder image
I regularly use Google Cloud Run to write functions using Python. When testing I am usually able to click "Test Function" at the top of the page which opens a console window at the bottom of the screen in order to run the function (this feature is only available for Python and Node.JS). I last used this feature earlier this week with no issues. No permissions have been altered on my project.
Now when I try to run "Test Function" I get the following error:
[5:37:05 PM] - Error: Command failed: cd /gcf-working-dir/function-sources && pack build gcf-ui-function --builder gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-22/python/builder --pull-policy if-not-present --env GOOGLE_FUNCTION_TARGET=hello_http --env GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE=cloudevent --env GOOGLE_DEVMODE=1 --env GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION=3.12
ERROR: failed to build: failed to fetch builder image 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-22/python/builder:latest': image 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-22/python/builder:latest' does not exist on the daemon: not found

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:826:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:900:15)
    at buildFunction (/app/app.runfiles/google3/cloud/console/web/functions/external/testing_server/workers/build_function_worker.js:17:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.runfiles/google3/cloud/console/web/functions/external/testing_server/workers/build_function_worker.js:35:131)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/main/worker_thread:183:24)
ERROR: failed to build: failed to fetch builder image 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-22/python/builder:latest': image 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-22/python/builder:latest' does not exist on the daemon: not found

This error occurs for any of the versions of Python available but the testing feature works normally if you select Node.JS. There are no manually configured Docker containers involved in this testing since it is a native feature of Cloud Run. I have done some searching for a fix but I'm also fairly new to GCP and could be missing something.
My instinct is that Google messed up the Python build images somehow (since 1.8 was decommed last week)
*edit: The function can be deployed with no errors, it's just using the Test Function feature that is bugged.
*edit 2: I've opened an issue with Google. Hopefully I can get an answer from them before too long. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/376097106

Got the same error minutes ago. I agree, it looks like a Google issue.

I'm getting the same error. I tried multiple Google Cloud accounts, and I have the same issue. It's definitely a bug on their side.

I suggest changing your service account to “App Engine Default Service Account” while setting configuration and re-test it.
If the error still occurred, you can try this another workaround, which you will create a separate service account for the event trigger with the following roles:
Cloud Build Service Account - required to access the builder images
Cloud Run Admin - grant permissions to manage Cloud Run
Cloud Functions Admin - grant permissions to manage Cloud Functions resources
EventArc Event Receiver - allowing the function to receive events properly
Storage Object Admin - provides access to Storage needed during the build
Artifact Registry Administrator - provide access to image registries needed during the build
When you deploy the function,  set --build-service-account and --trigger-service-account flags on the gcloud functions deploy command line.
